# Since adding role and membership information to my MVC application, I am having problems accessing the database. "login failed for user..."

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

Here's the stack trace, previously (before I introduced Roles and Membership) everything was fine. Now, I am getting the following error:
HEA21 is the name of the machine that SQL server is running on, HF is the domain.
I have added a user 'HF\HEA21$' and given them the db_owner role.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Login

```
failed for user 'HF\HEA21$'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Stack Trace
----------

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'HF\HEA21$'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'HF\HEA21$'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5063578
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +95
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +206
   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.RoleExists(String roleName) +489
   System.Web.Security.Roles.RoleExists(String roleName) +56
   Cadw.Web.Helpers.UserHelper.CreateUserInRole(String userAndRole) in D:\Development\CADW_AssetManagement\Cadw.Web\Helpers\UserHelper.cs:43
   Cadw.Web.Helpers.UserHelper.PopulateDefaultUsers() in D:\Development\CADW_AssetManagement\Cadw.Web\Helpers\UserHelper.cs:25
   Cadw.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in D:\Development\CADW_AssetManagement\Cadw.Web\Global.asax.cs:23

[HttpException (0x80004005): Login failed for user 'HF\HEA21$'.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9256973
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +131
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253

[HttpException (0x80004005): Login failed for user 'HF\HEA21$'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9171600
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +
```

256

---

Comment: By the way, my connection sgtring is: Data Source=HCA75;Initial Catalog=Assets_Pre_Release;Integrated Security=SSPI;

Comment: Have you tried logging in to SQL Management Studio using Windows auth while logged in as this user, and then try to open the database and select some records or something?

Comment: You'll want to check the DBServer->Security->Logins contains HF\HEA21$ as well as the actual Db you're trying to access, Assets_Pre_Release

Comment: Thank you Andrew Walters, this fixed it! Cheers.